# C++ Builder to Visual C++

Tags: c++, canvas, panel, c++builder

I have an application that is written with Borland C++ builder and now I have to write it in Visual Studio. I have Car.h and here you can see Car.cpp:

```
#include "Car.h"
#include "Form.h"

extern TForm1 *Form1;

Car::Car()
{
  aCanvas = Form1->FieldImage->Canvas;
  color = clYellow;
  .....
}

void Car::draw()
{
  aCanvas->Pen->Color = color;
  //aCanvas....
  //aCanvas....
  //some code for drawing....
}
```

Now, how to draw the that image in panel1 which is in Form? I dont know how to get rid of the Canvas and use a panel for drawing instead.

On Form1_Load I write:

```
 Car * car1;
 car1 = new Car;
 car1->draw();
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I recall having used C++ Builder for small support projects, Borland uses its own class library for C++ Builder. This library doesn not have direct substitute the Microsoft MFC/ATL class for the C++ Builder (I think they called thiers Object Windows Library (OWL) if I remember correctly) class.

Add to this that since I last used C++ Builder (are there any recent versions of it?) Microsoft has changed the behavior of some of thier classes in the MFC, especially the ones related to graphics.

You may need to figure out the mapping between the OWL you are using in C++ Builder and the version of the MFC/ATL for the version of Visual Studio that you are using.

In the end I believe you are still going to end up using a Canvas class to draw to, but how you get access to that Canvas class will change a little bit.

Comment: Borland C++ Builder uses VCL. OWL was used in the previous line of tools, Borland C++. OWL is more like MFC, but VCL is more like WinForms, so it will be near impossible to convert a VCL application to MFC.

Answer (score 0):

The Windows Forms framework is the closest MS framework to Borland C++ Builder VCL. But you may need to lear C# to use it. I am not sure if it is possible to use WinForms from C++/CLI.

Comment: "*I am not sure if it is possible to use WinForms from C++/CLI.*" It is, but I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: Well, I have finished this task and it is working. And there are a lot of differences from Borland C++ version. Actually, I always use C# when I have to create something. But this was a little job that I had to do and I had to use that C++/CLI. It was like first experience with C++.